# Access-PostgreSQL: Link tables as readonly, edit registers in form

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, odbc, access-control, vba

I have a PostgreSQL database working as backend and I have to develop an Access frontend solution for regular users of this database.

I decided it best to create some **forms** to manage the input, delition and deletion of data in the datbases, but as I am somewhat new to Access I may not be righ in my assumption here: if I **import tables** from the database into Access using the **linked-table** facility, and if I specify such connection as **read-only** (I want them to use the forms and the forms alone, least they screw everything up), when using the forms, they would connect to my Access's access of the tables, which is read-only, and thus edition, **addition and deletion will not be supported for the form**, right?

As I though of this, I also thought of creating a button on the form to change the table it is connected and bound to. Basically, it would open an ODBC connection to the real database and bind the form to the same table, but using different access rights.

Here comes the real question: how viable/useful/helpful/problem-solving is this solution and what VBA elements would I need to use? (I just learned about macros and VBA the last week)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532620/good-front-end-for-postgresql-on-windows-or-mac

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Comment: there are a lot of tools to use with postgresql.

Comment: @McNets I **have to** use access as the front end. Now, knowing this, I have explained my concern and a "plausible" way to create a workaround, and asked for someone with a larger expertise than me if it is a valid approach and what I would need to develop it _or_ if there is a different way to come around this.

Comment: @Feillen I know, but my experiences with MS-Access is not really good. Of course it's an easy way to design forms, but it's really expensive. Have you considered LibreOffice?

Comment: @mcNets I have a license for the application, and the final users will be using ms-access as well, so... (I personally like LibreOffice better and use it instead of MS Office :-)  )